# How to append positional arguments from a file.txt and use them for graphical shapes

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics, shapes

I have the positional arguments saved in a file, i have opened the file used keywords to get only the circle positionals saved those positionals to s and, when I try to say circle(s) it says I need more arguments even though their all inside of s.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Homework 10')
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
def circle(x, y, radius, color):
    canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + radius, y + radius, fill=color, outline=color)
def rectangle(x, y, width, height, color):
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+width, y+height, fill=color, outline=color)
def triangle(x, y, size, color):
    canvas.create_polygon(x-size//2, y, x+size//2, y, x, y-size//2, fill=color, 
outline=color)


def go():
    with open('file.txt') as (f):
        keywords = ('circle')
        for s in f:
            for word in s.split():
                if word in keywords:
                    s = (s[6:])
                    circle(s)
```

Comment: Please share a sample of the contents of `file.txt` and show how and where you call `go()`.

Comment: the function `go()` is not called, so it won't be executed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does something like this work?

```
"""
Assuming that files.txt contains information in the below format
circle 50 50 25 red
circle 100 100 50 blue
triangle 75 75 20 yellow
rectangle 200 200 100 150 purple
"""


from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Homework 10')
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg='white')
canvas.pack()
def circle(x, y, radius, color):
    x,y,radius = map(int,(x,y,radius))
    canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + radius, y + radius, fill=color, outline=color)
def rectangle(x, y, width, height, color):
    x,y,width,height = map(int,(x,y,width,height))
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+width, y+height, fill=color, outline=color)
def triangle(x, y, size, color):
    x, y, size = map(int,(x, y, size))
    canvas.create_polygon(x-size//2, y, x+size//2, y, x, y-size//2, fill=color, 
outline=color)


def go():
    with open('files.txt') as (f):
        keywords = ('circle','triangle','rectangle')
        for line in f.readlines():
            words =  line.strip().split(' ')
            
            function = words[0]            
            args = tuple(words[1:])
            
            if function == 'circle':
                circle(*args)
            if function == 'rectangle':
                rectangle(*args)
            if function == 'triangle':
                triangle(*args)

circle(50,50,25,'green')
root.after_idle(go)
root.mainloop()
```

You had a few errors in your code in terms of getting the different parts of each line.